# I can't see anything at all in my microscope

Tags: microscopy

I just got the Amscope M102C microscope, and it is the first microscope I've operated. I decided to try to look at a fly leg at 40x magnification, but all I could see were the blobs in your eye you get from looking at something bright, as well as a few dots that appear to be on the lens. I tried focusing, cleaning (even though it was fresh out of its package), but I still couldn't see anything. It's so blurry I can't even make out any shapes. Could I please have some help?

Comment: 40X is almost certainly an immersion objective, this type of objective isn't meant for looking at things like fly legs, it is meant for looking at tissues and cells. You are probably looking for a dissecting microscope. Hopefully your microscope came with some instructions.

Comment: Any 40X objective I've used is not an immersion lens. Furthermore, 40X magnification implies 4X objective and 10X ocular. But, yes, a dissecting microscope should be used for this application. Compound microscopes are not ideal for looking at thick, 3D objects.

Comment: Understood, but I've also observed (or tried to) onion skin, blades of grass, and a strand of hair and there would be no way of telling there was even anything under the microscope at all.

Comment: There are YouTube videos that will take you step-by-step through the process.

Comment: @BryanKrause All the 'students microscope' we used at college and university, contained a 40X or 45X objective  not to use with oil. Just like the 10X objective.

Comment: @canadianer Right you are - when I read the post at first I read it as the 40x objective rather than the full magnification. My mistake.

Comment: @canadianer err same mistake :P